# WKWebView didFinish – initial evaluateJavascript value of scrollHeight is incorrect

Tags: swift, swiftui, wkwebview

I have a Coordinator running evaluateJavascript on WkWebView `didFinish`.

The evaluate is getting the `document.body.scrollHeight` of the webView:

```
extension WebView {
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        var parent: WebView

        init(_ parent: WebView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            
            if webView.isLoading == false {
                webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight", completionHandler: { (height, _) in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.parent.dynamicHeight = height as! CGFloat
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's working fine for small web views, but for very large web views (HTML passed directly into WKWebView to render), the initial `scrollHeight` value returned from `evaluateJavascript` is incorrect.

For instance, with the above `self.parent.dynamicHeight` is returning `204187` when it should be `21675`.

If I wait 1 second after `didFinish` to evaluate, it's returning the correct value of `21675`, using a temp async/await task:

```
extension WebView {
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        var parent: WebView

        init(_ parent: WebView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            
            if webView.isLoading == false {
                Task.init {
                    do {
                        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_500_000_000)
                        let result = try await webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
                        self.parent.dynamicHeight = result as! CGFloat
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While the above async task works, it's causing 1 second delays in rendering the Webview, and XCode is warning about `WKWebView.evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:) must be used from main thread only`.

Regardless, I don't understand how it's returning the incorrect `scrollHeight` initially if `didFinish` should execute after the webview is finished loading.

Safari inspection of the Webview shows the HTML and BODY both have the correct height size.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59790493/12299030?

Comment: The Coordinator above, and the rest of the relevant code in my project is a modified version of the code snippet from the accepted answer in that SO question, so this is an issue which includes that accepted answer

Comment: If you'd gave a reference of used code in question I would not comment. Btw, that code still works for me.

Comment: It's a library which uses the SO answer: https://github.com/NuPlay/RichText . As I mentioned, for very large HTML files being loaded in WKWebView, it's giving incorrect initial scrollHeight values. For smaller files it works fine as mentioned

Comment: Note that in the linked question, the accepted answer recommends checking `document.readyState` in addition, and also recommends setting constraints correctly. I think those 2 issues might be the reason for your problems.

Comment: That worked thanks, I'll make a PR to the RichText git repo as well